# Shrinkwrap modifier with curvature control? – Machining inside corners

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am trying to create *form fitting* stands for some rocks that I 3d-scanned. What I've managed to do so far is to create a 3d-printable version. To produce the negative form I shrinkwrapped a plane on my scanned object (to blockout undercuts) and cut it out of a solid with the boolean modifier. That worked incredibly well.

Now I would like to mill such form-fitting stands out of wood.
Unlike with 3d printing, I can't machine sharp inside corners with the cnc-router.

--> https://makeitfrommetal.com/machining-square-inside-corners-the-nightmare/

**Is it possible to limit the shrinkwrap modifier so that the plane clings to the surface of the stone without producing sharp corners?** The smallest inside curvature has to be limited to the radius of the ball- or endmill I am using (5-8mm).

Does anyone know a different method which could solve the problem?

Comment: Hello. Not sure to understand: this is for a real wood milling? If so what do you expect to be in 3d on Blender? A model that could be printed and help for the mill?

Comment: Hello lemon! Thank you so much for writing back. Yes, what I want to try is to mill a similar holder for the stone, but out of wood. Unfortunately I cannot mill out small inner radii with the milling machine. This means that if I were to simply mill the negative shape with the blocked out undercuts (as I did with the 3d printer), the stone would not fit because the sharp corners were not cut out.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in Blender to modify the surface of the stone to 'blockout' sharp edges that cannot be milled as a negative.

Comment: What if: use particles with object (maybe a cylinder) with a size of 5-8mm. Convert all as mesh and use the boolean again?